# Most efficient way of sorting ObservableCollection<T> with a new item in it

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I have ViewModel class as follows:

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<InfoItem> List { get; set; }
}

public interface InfoItem
{
  int Reference { get; }
  string Name { get; }
}
```

The collection is sorted by Name which is being displayed in the UI. I have a scenario where the collection contains a couple of thousand items and I add a new item to the collection.

What is the most efficient way to re-sort my collection by Name so that the new item appears in the correct place in the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your collection is sorted already, then perform a binary search on it to find out where you should insert the new item, and then call [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411.aspx). Adding the item to the end and then resorting the whole collection would be very wasteful.

It's a shame there isn't a general-purpose `BinarySearch` extension method on `IList<T>`, but it shouldn't be too hard to write. Assuming you'd want to write a generic method to do this (which I'd suggest you do - it won't be significantly harder than writing an `InfoItem`-specific one) you'd *either* want to take an `IComparer<T>` *or* a projection, e.g.

```
public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer)
```

or

```
public static int BinarySearch<TSource, TKey>(
    this IList<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

I suggest you make the return value follow the convention from [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx), such that if a match is not found, it returns the bitwise negation of the index where the item would be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Since your collection is already sorted, just [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411.aspx) the new item at the appropriate location which you can discover with a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Unfortunately there is not a built-in binary search on `IList<T>` but you can easily make an extension method that does the job. Be careful when you implement binary search that you do not introduce a [classic bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5045582) (the bug is a possible overflow in computing the average of the `low` and `high` indexes as `low + high` might overflow). You could use [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx) as a template.

Comment: I highly recommend Pex (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) for testing algorithms like binary search. I know from experience that it finds that overflow bug and similar issues immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Follow @JonSkeet answer, I made the BinarySearch extension of IList, similar to [.NET sourcecode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,276):

```
public static class IListBinarySearchHelper {
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> source, int index, int count, T item, IComparer<T> comparer) {
        if (index < 0) throw new Exception("Need non negative number of index.");
        if (count < 0) throw new Exception("Need non negative number of count.");
        if (source.Count - index < count) throw new Exception("Invalid offset length of count.");
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() <= index + count);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        return Array.BinarySearch<T>(source.Cast<T>().ToArray(), index, count, item, comparer);
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> source, T item) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() <= source.Count);
        return BinarySearch(source, 0, source.Count, item, null);
    }

    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> source, T item, IComparer<T> comparer) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() <= source.Count);
        return BinarySearch(source, 0, source.Count, item, comparer);
    }
}
```

So now we can do:

```
var nums = new ObservableCollection<int>();
nums.Add(1);
nums.Add(3);
nums.Add(8);

var result = nums.BinarySearch(1);   /// return 0
result = nums.BinarySearch(4);       /// return -3
```

This works perfect to me.

The return value follow same rule with `Array.BinarySearch`, positive number for the found index, negative number for the hint of insertion point.

> What is the most efficient way to re-sort my collection by Name so
> that the new item appears in the correct place in the list?

To answer the question, just insert the value at the point related to BinarySearch return value.

Comment: You are copying the whole array in `source.Cast<T>().ToArray()`...